# ImportError: No module named mako.util when running airflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, mako, airflow

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on here: http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/tutorial.html

but i'm using a mac, and so i had to install python via `brew`, which then comes with `pip`, which i used to install `airflow`.  However, that didn't quite work either, so i then tried to create a `virtualenv` for which i tried to install `airflow` and it is still giving me this `ImportError: No module named mako.util`

not sure if it matters, but here's my setup:

```
(airflow) [davidtian: airflow]$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
(airflow) [davidtian: airflow]$ pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /Users/someone/Desktop/blah/airflow/airflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
(airflow) [davidtian: airflow]$
```

How do i install this `mako.util` module?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. after trying a bunch of things. for one, the python that comes with Mac apparently doesn't work very well. you have to `brew install python` instead. with that python, it comes with `pip` by default

i had to actually `sudo pip uninstall airflow` and then install it again.